# Unity UI panel transparency

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, unity-ui

I'm working on my game and I want to add an inventory type system, when I added the panel it was a little transparent while the one in the video was watching was not. I didn’t see any setting for transparency in the Unity inspector for both the canvas and the panel. The UI mode is an overlay

I didn’t try much other than clicking all the check boxes, and I was excepting for the up to be a solid color.

Comment: The Unity2d tag doesn’t exist but it is 2d for those wondering

Comment: on the `Image` component check the color .. by default (when using `Panel`) it has alpha = 0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to go to colors and slide this slider all the way up or down [(the slider you need to change)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eTNu.jpg)

Comment: You can accept your own answer as the correct answer

Comment: konekoya, Its telling me to wait a day to accept it

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [Canvas Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/class-CanvasGroup.html) in your hierarchy, it can come from here (Alpha property).

Comment: There’s only 1 panel and 1 canvas so alpha property wouldn’t be true for the case

Answer (score -1):

Change the alpha in the color attribute of the image component every panel comes with a default image component of alpha 0.5

Comment: Please do not repeat existing answers.